# How to use a string to go to a URL in Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

in my template, I have a DOM element with an id.

```
<h1 id="club-title">{{club.title}}</h1>
```

Something like this.

This is for a view called **club_detail**. The url for this view is in **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^club/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.club_detail, name='club_detail'),
```

In one of my views, I want to go to the url above, but I also want to add '#club-title' to the end of the url so that the browser scrolls down to my element. How do I do this?

Currently, the view looks something like this:

```
def index(request):
    .....
    return redirect('myapp:club_detail', pk = str(club.pk))
```

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reverse` to get the url and then add `#club-title` to the string:

```
def index(request):
    .....
    return redirect('%s#club-title' % reverse('myapp:club_detail', pk=str(club.pk)))
```